# Windows 11 Hyper-V freezes on startup

Tags: windows-11

I have had both Windows 10 and 11 virtual machines installed in Hyper-V. Because of some issues I had to uninstall them.
Now in reinstalling the Windows 10 went OK. But Windows 11 is not working. In choosing 'generation 2' both Windows 10 and 11 freezes before installing. They  freeze at 'press any key to boot'and don't install. No keyboard controls at this point.
Any solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were the machines Generation 2 to begin with?  Generation cannot be changed. Did you properly export the VMs before reinstalling?  ...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/export-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: I am beyond exporting and importing. I want to do a fresh install. Plan and hopefully simple.

Comment: Fresh install is the answer I have given you here..

Comment: Use the Windows ISO files to build new machines.

Answer (score 0):

Before uninstalling or reinstalling, you need to back up or export the Virtual Machines. Export is easier. Please review both links below.

Also, machine Generation cannot be changed once set.

If Virtual Machines were damaged before you had a chance to back them up or export them, it may be easier in the long run just to rebuild them.

Use the Windows ISO files to build new machines.

[Back Up Hyper-V machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-hyper-v-virtual-machines?view=sc-dpm-2022)

> Host vs Guest backup
>
> DPM can perform a host or guest-level backup of Hyper-V VMs. At the
> host level, the DPM protection agent is installed on the Hyper-V host
> server or cluster and protects the entire VMs and data files running
> on that host. At the guest level, the agent is installed on each
> virtual machine and protects the workload present on that machine.
>
> Both methods have pros and cons:
>
> Host-level backups are flexible because they work regardless of the
> type of OS running on the guest machines and don't require the
> installation of the DPM protection agent on each VM. If you deploy
> host-level backup, you'll be able to recover an entire virtual machine
> or files and folders (item-level recovery).
>
> Guest-level backup is useful if you want to protect specific workloads
> running on a virtual machine. At host-level you can recover an entire
> VM or specific files, but it won't provide recovery in the context of
> a specific application. For example, to be able to recover specific
> SharePoint items from a backed-up VM, you should do guest-level backup
> of that VM. You must use guest-level backup if you want to protect the
> data stored on passthrough disks. Passthrough allows the virtual
> machine to directly access the storage device and doesn't store
> virtual volume data in a VHD file.

[Export Hyper-V machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/export-and-import-virtual-machines)

> Export a Virtual Machine An export gathers all required files into one
> unit--virtual hard disk files, virtual machine configuration files,
> and any checkpoint files. You can do this on a virtual machine that is
> in either a started or stopped state.
>
> Using Hyper-V Manager to create a virtual machine export:
>
> In Hyper-V Manager, right-click the virtual machine and select Export.
>
> Choose where to store the exported files, and click Export.
>
> When the export is done, you can see all exported files under the
> export location.